# Do psuedo selectors work in styled-components the same as in css with unicode characters

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components

I have the following styled-component, and I am trying to add a unicode character `\00d7` as the content for a pseudo selector, which is a cross or close icon.

However this doesn't seem to work as it would in css. Of course I can use an svg for this close icon as an alternative, I was just curious if this is possible with styled-components? It seems to allow blank pseudo selector's though e.g. `''`

```
const Close = styled.span`
  color: pink;
  &:before {
    content: '\00d7';
  }
`
```

Comment: Is this issue observed in all browsers or any specific browser?

Comment: Try using `'\d7'`

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the answer, not having used the tech, but from a basic JavaScript standpoint, you've got a string within a string. So, the first pass at the outer string the escaped character will be interpreted as JS would. Namely, a null character (`\0`) followed by three characters. I'd suggest escaping the backslash, i.e., `content: '\\00d7';`.

Comment: Unfortunately neither of those worked `'\d7'` or `'\\00d7'` and the issue is present on all browsers.

Comment: Double backslash worked for me. A single backslash used to work with styled-components. Not sure what they changed here.

Comment: What does  &:  signifies here ?

Answer (score 26):

I think you need a combination of the two comments:

```css
content: "\\d7"
```

This works for me.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try updating the reference to:

```
content: '&times;';
```

Further alternative encoding formats are available on https://brajeshwar.github.io/entities/.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. However interestingly copy pasting the symbol in: `content: '×';` did work. So thank you for the link.

Answer (score 0):

See if the problem isn't the quotes

```
content: '"\\00d7"'
```

I had this issue when using props with a ternary operator