# How to put React.Component to CSS content property (in :before/:after pseudo-elements)?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components, react-component

In `styled-components`, I'm trying to get a React Icon to render on hover by passing it through `content` but for some reason, my render on hover is `[Object Object]`.

Component:

```js
export const FooLink = styled(Link)`
  padding: 0.5rem 2rem;
  color: ${({ theme }) => theme.colors.white};
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  font-size: ${({ theme }) => theme.fontSizes.p};
  letter-spacing: 0.15em;
  transition: ${({ theme }) => theme.animations.trans3};

  &:after {
    content: '${FaArrowRight}';
    /* content: '>'; */
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    right: -${({ theme }) => theme.spacings.small};
    transition: ${({ theme }) => theme.animations.trans3};
  }

  &:hover {
    padding-right: ${({ theme }) => theme.spacings.small};
    padding-left: ${({ theme }) => theme.spacings.xxSmall};
  }

  &:hover:after {
    opacity: 1;
    ${({ theme }) => theme.spacings.xSmall};
  }
`
```

Ive brought everything in with:

```
import styled from 'styled-components'
import { Link } from 'gatsby'
import { FaArrowRight } from 'react-icons/fa'
```

Other attempts on content

```
content: ${FaArrowRight};
```

But I found this won't work per:

> That is because content value must be within quotes in CSS.

Realizing I might have spent too long in a CSS mental state I tried bringing in React:

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import { Link } from 'gatsby'
import { FaArrowRight } from 'react-icons/fa'
```

And rendering:

```
content: '${(<FaArrowRight />)}';
```

when I try with template literals I get an error with missing semi-colons:

```
content: `'${<FaArrowRight />}'`;
```

All attempts render as `[Object Object]`

Research to see if this has been asked and I've read through:

- [How to render pseudo before content dynamically in styled-component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46339034/how-to-render-pseudo-before-content-dynamically-in-styled-component)
- [Before and After pseudo classes used with styled-components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45871439/before-and-after-pseudo-classes-used-with-styled-components)
- [css pseudo code “li::before” in react inline style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45730224/css-pseudo-code-libefore-in-react-inline-style)
- [How do I get a variable from a graphQl query into a pseudo element in either inline styles or styled components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59314237/how-do-i-get-a-variable-from-a-graphql-query-into-a-pseudo-element-in-either-inl)
- [Do psuedo selectors work in styled-components the same as in css with unicode characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44116497/do-psuedo-selectors-work-in-styled-components-the-same-as-in-css-with-unicode-ch)

In `styled-components` how can I render a React Icon in `content`?

Comment: stick a `&` before `:after`

Comment: ya that was an edit mistake but even then it still renders as `object object`

Comment: `'${FaArrowRight}'` Use back ticks instead of single quotes.

Comment: @TomBombadil as explained in the question, from my research, single quotes should be used with `content` instead of template literals.

Comment: As far as I know you can't pass an objects as value to content. And I think you are passing an object. Not sure if `FaArrowRight` is a string or an object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you need to use [`styled-components`](https://styled-components.com) (or any other CSS-in-JS library) with an icon from [`react-icons`](https://react-icons.github.io/react-icons/) (or any other library that exports a [`React.Component`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html) which renders an [`<svg>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/svg) element), I see the only one way: to transform a component to an [`url()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/url()) with a markup string because only this way you can pass an image to [`content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content) property in your case. For that transformation, you need: [`React.createElement()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#createelement), [`ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html#rendertostaticmarkup) and [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent). Also, you can use [Base64](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Base64) instead.

This one works ([CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-bohr-mwkvu?file=/src/index.js)):

```
import { createElement } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { renderToStaticMarkup } from "react-dom/server";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { Link } from "gatsby";
import { FaArrowRight } from "react-icons/fa";

window.___loader = { enqueue: () => {}, hovering: () => {} };

const reactSvgComponentToMarkupString = (Component, props) =>
  `data:image/svg+xml,${encodeURIComponent(
    renderToStaticMarkup(createElement(Component, props))
  )}`;

const FooLink = styled(Link)`
  ${({ color }) => color && `color: ${color};`}
  &:after {
    content: ${({ color }) =>
      `url(${reactSvgComponentToMarkupString(FaArrowRight, {
        color
      })})`};
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
  }

  &:hover:after {
    opacity: 1;
  }
`;

render(
  <>
    <div>
      <FooLink to="/test1" color="red">
        Link with arrow (red)
      </FooLink>
    </div>
    <div>
      <FooLink to="/test2">Link with arrow (default)</FooLink>
    </div>
  </>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Thanks to [this Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/kevinweber/3c519c32db6c976e9cbb5565dc3822f1).

Comment: I can bring in the component but for some reason it will not take any color applied. Any suggestions for applying the color?

Comment: @DᴀʀᴛʜVᴀᴅᴇʀ how do you pass a color?

Comment: I've tried adding color:red and fill:red to :after but the svg still renders black

Comment: @DᴀʀᴛʜVᴀᴅᴇʀ added the color prop to the code, check out, please.

Comment: I'll take the opportunity to learn as I know nothing about the tool, Is it needed to use CSS2 `:after` (instead of CSS3 `::after`) in styled-components?

Comment: @Leo no, it's your choice.

Comment: @sergdenisov the color prop is not working for me. I do not require it as an argument from an element but a hardcoded value of #1F5462. My code looks like  `url(${reactSvgComponentToMarkupString(FaCircle, 'color: #1F5462')})`}; but it doesn't work and still takes black. Also i would like to control width and height. how do I include them as well?

Comment: @SimeonMarkFernandes you need to write `url(${reactSvgComponentToMarkupString(FaCircle, { color: '#1F5462' })})`. You also can add `width` and `height` props similar to my `color` prop.