# how to use react icon in css

Tags: css, reactjs

Is there any way to use react-icons in css before and after pseudo class

Specific:
I am talking about the this library
https://react-icons.github.io/react-icons/

Comment: yeah, looks like you can, but seems like an overkill - https://stackoverflow.com/a/66892699/949195